# ¿Cómo puedo instalar MongoDB?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, windows10

Al momento de ejecutar MongoDB y presionar "instalar" después de unos segundos me aparece esta ventana

[image]

ya lo he intentado muchas veces y obtengo el mismo resultado. ¿Tengo que instalar otra cosa antes de ejecutar?

Comment: Elimina ese archivo, descarga de nuevo, intenta de nuevo. Saludos.

Comment: Parece ser un problema común, [ya intentaste ésto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60099473/mongodb-msi-installer-not-working-on-windows-10)

Comment: @fredyfx ya lo intente 3 veces y sigue igual

Comment: Si tienes un disco duro mecánico, aplica una defragmentación, es probable que haya sectores dañados que estén interfiriendo el proceso. Saludos.